# Does anybody know why 2-finger scrolling doesn't work after re-installing windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, touchpad, thinkpad, scrolling

I have a dual-boot laptop, one SSD with Linux the other with Windows10. Windows10 doesn't respnd to any scrolling action, it doesn't do anything when scrolling with 2 fingers or when I use the scroll button (4) and the joystick (it's a ThinkPad).
[image: When you press and hold 4 you're supposed to be able to scroll using the red joystick.]

I alreadt tried most of the solutions from these articles:

https://softwarekeep.com/help-center/two-finger-scroll-not-working-windows-10-fixed

https://slovakiahoster.com/

I think the trackpad might be registered as a mouse since that's the only thing that apears in the Registry Editor. I know it's not a hardware problem because everythin works perfectrly on the other OS with the same hardware. Does anybody know how to fix it? I would like to be able to scroll with the 2 finger gesture.

Comment: Try using Lenovo System Update to update the Synaptics and Mouse drivers.

Comment: Have an external mouse ready, you'll likely need to uninstall the incorrect/conflicting device driver.  You can use a utility like `rapr.exe` to remove from driverstore prior to installation.  I'm assumig you ran a clean install rather than from system imaging?